# HTTP 500 error when fetching access token via EWS API with Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

One of our customers with on-premise Exchange Server is having hard time obtaining access token with our Officejs Outlook add-in.

While calling Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync via EWS API, we see the following error.

```
HTTPRequestFailure: The request has failed. 
Please look at the diagnostics object for the HTTP error code.
{"HTTPCode":"500"}
```

The error occurs at random but when it does it persists until Outlook is relaunched.

When EWS returns an error, it also returns a big XML payload that states the error, however as we deal through the SDK we don’t see the payload.

Of note, they have different EWS internal URL and external URL, and they have a CAS, six mailbox servers and two archive servers (this is based on data exposed by their Autodiscover URL metadata JSON). All are using the same namespace autodiscover.obfuscated_company_name.com.

As we don't have access to their Exchange logs, it's difficult to obtain more information unless we can

a) instruct the customer where to look and what

b) find a way to get the detailed error message through to our platform

NOTE: There is an eerily similar (solved and closed) case here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1646
(TLDR: due to a bug, Outlook could call internal EWS endpoint when it should've called external endpoint, and vice versa.)

We have already verified the customer is running Outlook client version+build that includes the aforementioned fix.

Outlook version: 16.0.13801.20864

Browser used by add-ins: Edge 18.19042

QUESTIONS:

1. As developers, how can we obtain more information of the actual error message thrown the the customer's environment?
2. Does this sound like:

- a misconfigured internal or external URL for EWS VirtualDirectory?
- an expired SSL cert on one mailbox server?
- a redirect of internal client from internal url to external url because of DNS misconfiguration?
- IIS problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Similar to the github link you referenced, you can try to capture the customer's fiddler trace and see what responses we are seeing from EWS. Specifically the responses from the calls getCallbackToken made to exchange.asmx.

Comment: Are there any other ways to collect analytics from add-in side than Fiddler? The problem is occurring at random and on end-user devices we have hard time getting Fiddler installed. I keep pushing for it though...

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a good recommendation to diagnose this problem as it happens randomly. We have received a few cases about this API, but we have yet to get a solid repro. This is issue has been put into our backlog and we will be analyzing what's going on with logs and investigate internally but currently we do not have a timeline to share.

Comment: As this is an OnPrem server, this may require a support case to get the appropriate support resources devoted to the case. Does your Customer have a support account with Microsoft that they can engage?

Comment: Another debugging resource that you could use is the diagnostic object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.asyncresult?view=excel-js-preview#diagnostics. This object is returned as part of the asyncResult in the callback of getTokenCallbackAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#getCallbackTokenAsync_options__callback_.

Comment: The diagnostics object includes information, including the HTTP error code and the error message if the request fails. The diagnostic object should also include the clientRequestId (this is not documented). It may be helpful if you could log and share the entire JSON in the diagnostic object with us.